# How to color measure value with condition in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

table:

```
id    category    qty    sales_2017   sales_2018
1     pen          5       5000         7000
1     pen          8       15000        7000
1     pen          9       15000        7000
2     pencil       6       5000         17000
2     pencil       1       5000         14000
2     pencil      10       5000         7000
```

output:

```
category   qty   sales_2018(sales_2018-sales_2017)
pen        22     35000(-14000)
pencil     17     15000(20000)
```

i need to get output like this, with the color formatted which are in bracket if it is negative then red
else green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For as close to the desired output as possible, you need to drag Category to the Rows shelf, then SUM(qty) to rows, SUM(sales_2018) to rows.

Now, for the conditional formatting on the bracket data, you need a simple calculated field for 2018 -2017 sales. Drag this to the text card.

To color that text accordingly, write a calculated field:

IF [calculated field you just created above] < 0 THEN 'red' ELSE 'green' END

Drag that calculated field to the color card and choose colors to match their names (aliases). You can do this by double clicking on the colors in the legend.

If you need to add parentheses around the result you can do that in the label card.